# VSCode TS error with React.forwardRef functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

We are using JavaScript (not TypeScript) to write our component library, and we have `checkJs: true` in our project's `jsconfig.json` file.

All of our components are functional components (no class components). When a component requires a ref, we use `React.forwardRef`.

An example of a component for the sake of this question; not an actual component, but shows how we write our components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import propTypes from './propTypes';

export const Box = React.forwardRef(({ padding, children }, ref) => {
  return (
    <View ref={ref} style={{ padding }}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
});

Box.propTypes = propTypes;
```

However, this causes this "red squiggly line" error under the `padding` prop:

> Property 'padding' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)

And where the `propTypes` is assigned:

> Type '{ padding: Requireable; }' has no properties in common with type 'WeakValidationMap<RefAttributes>'.ts(2559)

And when implementing this `<Box>` component, the red squiggly line appears under the component's name, and the error is:

> Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.ts(2559)

The code itself is valid, and changing `checkJs` to `false` resolves this, but we want to keep `checkJs` `true`.

What exactly are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with `propTypes`, but you can define both the props and the ref type by setting the generics on `forwardRef`:

```
export const Box = React.forwardRef<View, {padding?: string | number}>(({ padding, children }, ref) => {
  return (
    <View ref={ref} style={{ padding }}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG84A1YJAdzgF85tcCj0MALQA7FDGAA3JGSpUkAD1rw0EEQGd4AIQgK4AXkTEYAOkzQ2KKABNkmADwt2AGgZgU168BEBzAPwAXHCaUN4%20cAA%20cCIAriAARkhQnAB8ABRpjO6eYa5oABbAADbWRCJcrkSYAJQGKQxUcHBEMDFQ5WmNTXCOrBxV%20vRV3JoAnkVIg1keXr5cqV3dDAXFpUginIs9APRObCld1RSUnEdAA)